# Novice question about Averages - Sports Analytics

Tags: mean, descriptive-statistics, games

I came across a post by the SEC showcasing teams’ home record during the past 5 seasons.
[image: SEC Teams' Home Record]

Although Alabama ranks first for having the most won games at home, I questioned the fairness of the average win rate as some teams played less/more home games than others.

[image: SEC Teams' Home Record - Average]

From my understanding, normalizing scales each input variable separately to the range 0 – 1, making it useful when dealing with multiple variables measured on different scales.

And, standardization tells you how many standard deviations from the mean.

So, in this case, would standardizing the data be the better option in calculating the average home win rate although the data isn't Normal?

I tried simplifying the question, by comparing two teams with the same win average.
[image: Two Teams Stats]
Would statistics be the wrong method for this problem due to the sample number of observations?

Comment: I think one option may be a weighted average.

Comment: There isn't much you can do about the mean estimates as such, standardization won't help. You could run say an ANOVA, where you would get an estimate for the mean AND an estimate for the standard deviation (error) of said means, this would allow you to compare groups of unequal sizes, to check if a difference is significant.